# Tooltips in Geany: improve or disable?

Tags: gui, configuration, geany, tooltip

Ubuntu 20.04.1
Theme: Yaru light
Geany v 1.36

In Geany, mouse-over tooltips have a big padding and are positioned such that they regularly cover up the things I am trying to look at.

The unnecessary tooltips are especially annoying when trying to navigate the file-browser in the sidebar.

Is there a way to disable them?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of a mouse-over tooltip seen in Geany]

Comment: In the meanwhile I have found out that these are the Gnome desktop's tooltips that are present in other applications as well. I still have not found a way to customize their behaviour. Just a guess: maybe it could be possible to alter their appearance somewhat in a custom gnome shell theme.